How to interact TrustZone-TrustedFirmware-a from Linux World
I am a newbie to TrustZone and TF-a, and I want to access some functionalities, such as getting an attestation token. However, it is not clear how to interact with TZ Secure World and TF-a from NonSecure Linux World.
And I am also not a Linux expert, but I need to work in the Linux world.
Is there any examples, I suppose TF-a provides drivers/libraries and APIs to include and call?
Thank you in advance.
